# How to statistically compare groups for multiple density plots?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, chi-squared-test, density-function

Is there a statistical method to compare these density plots other than ANOVA (MANOVA)? I would like to compare the densities among year within each plot and report which of those distributions are "significantly different". The reason is that I am more interested in the spread and where on the distribution of the dataset rather than solely on the mean and variance. Thanks

Here is the code and plot

```
ggplot(NMPSCFAM, aes(Length, colour= Year)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), alpha=0.3) + xlim(0, 700) +  
  geom_density(aes(colour = Year)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab(expression(paste("Mean density ( ", m^2, ")", sep = ""))) +
facet_wrap( ~ Family + Sector2, ncol=3, scales = "free")
```

[image]

---

Edit: Ok so no answers so far. If I did these density plots in a histogram would there be a way to do a Chi-square test on each of the plots? Could any one help me out on how to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a chi-square is it ignores the ordering, leading to a loss of power.

One possibility: there is a [k-group version of a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2238210)$^{[1]}$.

Another is a k-sample Anderson-Darling test. E.g. see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Non-parametric_k-sample_tests).

A third possibility might be to look at an orthogonal-polynomial decomposition of a chi-square (or rather the first few terms in one), which would then be taking account of the ordering. See, for example chapter 6 of Best (1999)$^{[2]}$.

[1]:  Conover, W. J.  (1965),
"Several k-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Tests",
*The Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, **36**:3 (Jun.), pp. 1019-1026

[2]:  Best, D.J. (1999),
*Tests of fit and other nonparametric data analysis*,
PhD Thesis, School of Mathematics and Applied Statistics, University of Wollongong
http://ro.uow.edu.au/theses/2061   ([direct link](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3061&context=theses))

Comment: thanks for this. I was discussing an orthogonal-polynomial decomposition of a chi-square and thought this may be beyond me. I'll source those papers and have a read. Now to figure out which one and to complete it in R. Once done I'll get back to this post with the results. Regards George

Comment: There are some papers that discuss this possibility (some by Rayner and Best) as well. If you can't find any I should be able to dig some up.