# Check if density plots are significantly different (with R)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, treatment-effect

I have daily data on cars per minute passing certain points. The data covers weekdays of 4 months, July and August, for 2013 and 2014. In August 2014 a toll (treatment) was introduced. I would like to test if there is a statistically significant variation in the volume of cars during this month.

I am unsure on how could I give some statistical ground to my analysis going beyond pure visual comparison of trends.

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113002/how-to-statistically-compare-groups-for-multiple-density-plots) they ask on how to statistically compare groups of multiple density plots. I think my question goes on those lines, but I have many plots within a month, and I need to compare months among themselves to see if there is an effect of the treatment (August 2014). Besides this, there is no R implementation of it.

Any idea on how to assess the effect of the treatment using R?

[image: Example with loess trend]

Edit based on @Hunaphu answer:

1. Only August '14 is treated, so actually I took into account the July months to control for the year effect. Given the loess trends, 2014 shows lower volumes and that wouldn't be a treatment effect. Likewise, July months seem to have higher volumes so, should I define $X_t$ as:

$X_t = f(t) + f(t)*Treatment + f(t)*July + \sigma G_t$

where the binary variables $Treatment = 0$ for both July’13 and August’13, and $July = 1$ for July’13. Likewise,

$Z_t = f(t+1) + f(t+1)*Treatment + f(t+1)*July + \sigma G_t$

Is this correct? My research question would it be if $Treatment$ is significant, right?

2. As important as the means is the shape of the curve, so a change in the shape of August’14 with respect to the others will also be an “treatment effect”. How to assess for significant changes in shape to complement my visual assessment?

Comment: Plots are just a visual representation of data - to check if the *plots* differ you can just judge it by looking at them. *What* do you want to compare?

Comment: The comparison is: Are the vehicle volumes shown in August 2014 significantly different from those of other months? 
I would like to know if there is any statistical analysis that could be done beyond the visual comparison of plots.

Comment: Welcome to this site! In response to your flag, rather than deleting this question and posting a new one, I would suggest to clarify it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could form the difference process and study that.

Let $X_t$ be the data from '13 and $Y_t$ the data from '14. Define $Z_t = X_t - Y_t$.

Assume that $X_t = f(t) + \sigma G_t$, where $G_t \sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Then if $Y_t$ follows the same distribution, you should have $Z_t = 2\sigma H_t$ in distribution, where $H$ also is standard normal.

The assumption that $X$ is defined as a deterministic function plus noise is strong but, in my view, reasonable.

Based on the plot I think that you will find that $Z_t$ does not have mean zero.

Short form:
Define $Z_t$. Estimate the mean of the process. If it is not zero then reject the hypothesis that $f(t)$ is the model for both $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it really gives a mathematical setting to the research question. I have edited the question at the end based on your answer.